# Using toString in java can't find symbol error?

Tags: java

I've been trying to use getters and setters along with toString and I'm having trouble seeing what the issue is with my code. I'm not sure where the problem lies exactly. 
So, am i supposed to have a main? I'm unsure if thats needed or not in this situation.

Also, is there any way i could better format the "Rectangle(x, x)" It looks kinda weird the way it is at the moment.

```
public class Rectangle {
// DO NOT MODIFY THE INSTANCE VARIABLES
// begin instance variables
private int width;
private int height;
// end instance variables

// TODO - write your code below this comment.
// You need to do the following:
//
// 1.) Define a constructor which takes two ints
//     representing the width and height, respectively.
//     The constructor should set its instance variables
//     equal to these values.
//
// 2.) Define a "getter" named getWidth, which returns
//     the width of the rectangle.
//
// 3.) Define a "getter" named getHeight, which returns
//     the height of the rectangle.
//
// 4.) Define a "setter" named setWidth, which takes
//     the new width of the rectangle and sets the
//     rectangle's width to that value.
//
// 5.) Define a "setter" named setHeight, which
//     takes the new height of the rectangle and sets
//     the rectangle's height to that value
//
// 6.) Define a toString method, which returns
//     a String representation of the rectangle.
//     As an example, if the width of the rectangle is
//     3 and the height of the rectangle is 4, this should
//     return the String:
//
//     "Rectangle(3, 4)"
//
public Rectangle(int rectWidth, int rectHeight) {
    rectWidth = width;
    rectHeight = height;
}
public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}
public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
public void setWidth(int rectWidth) {
    width = rectWidth;
}
public void setheight(int rectHeight) {
    height = rectHeight;
}
public String toString() {
    return s;
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle s = new Rectangle("Rectangle"+"("+rectWidth+", 
"+rectHeight+")");
    System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: But please make it a *minimal* example. The comments etc are not relevant. Now, you appear to be trying to call a `Rectangle(String)` constructor that doesn't exist, using variables `rectWidth` and `rectHeight` that aren't in scope. It's not clear how you expect that to work.

Comment: I suspect the first line of your `main` method should be `Rectangle s = new Rectangle(3, 4);` for example.

Comment: Then your `toString()` method is trying to return `s`, which isn't a field in the class...

Comment: Additionally, I don't think your constructor does what it should. You want to assign the parameters to the attributes, not the other way around. Change with 
    this.width = rectWidth;
    this.height = rectHeight;

Comment: Best to have your main function in a separate class. Also, your toString should return the "Rectangle"+"("+rectWidth+", "+rectHeight+")" part that you currently have in your main function

Comment: @mdewit I tried it and im getting "error: cannot find symbol" on rectWidth and rectHeight. This is after I changed my constructor to this.x = x

Comment: Inside toString, you are going to have to use your class fields. So do this: return "Rectangle(" + this.width + ", " + this.height + ")";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things: your constructor was incorrect:

You need to set the instance variables for "this" object that you are creating, and you must call the constructor with the correct arguments.
ToString should be used to obtain a string representation of this particular instance of Rectangle. Try this:

```
public class Rectangle {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THE INSTANCE VARIABLES
    // begin instance variables
    private int width;
    private int height;
    // end instance variables

    // TODO - write your code below this comment.
    // You need to do the following:
    //
    // 1.) Define a constructor which takes two ints
    //     representing the width and height, respectively.
    //     The constructor should set its instance variables
    //     equal to these values.
    //
    // 2.) Define a "getter" named getWidth, which returns
    //     the width of the rectangle.
    //
    // 3.) Define a "getter" named getHeight, which returns
    //     the height of the rectangle.
    //
    // 4.) Define a "setter" named setWidth, which takes
    //     the new width of the rectangle and sets the
    //     rectangle's width to that value.
    //
    // 5.) Define a "setter" named setHeight, which
    //     takes the new height of the rectangle and sets
    //     the rectangle's height to that value
    //
    // 6.) Define a toString method, which returns
    //     a String representation of the rectangle.
    //     As an example, if the width of the rectangle is
    //     3 and the height of the rectangle is 4, this should
    //     return the String:
    //
    //     "Rectangle(3, 4)"
    //
    public Rectangle(int rectWidth, int rectHeight) {
        // "this" refers to the instance of Rectangle you are creating
        // so this objects width and height are set to the values passed into the constructor...
        this.width = rectWidth;
        this.height = rectHeight;
    }
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public void setWidth(int rectWidth) {
        width = rectWidth;
    }
    public void setheight(int rectHeight) {
        height = rectHeight;
    }
    public String toString() {
        // the toString returns a string representation for "this" object
        return "Rectangle(" + this.width + "," + this.height + ")";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle s = new Rectangle(5,4);
                System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```